# Unable to use a docker-container as the php interpreter in PhpStorm on Windows

Tags: docker, phpstorm

I use docker-tools to run docker on Windows 7. I have the docker-machine setup and the commands I run from the command line work fine.

I'm now trying to integrate this in PhpStorm. Here are the 2 things I tried:

**1. As a local interpreter**

I made `php.bat` with the following content

```
@echo off

SET DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
SET DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
SET DOCKER_CERT_PATH=C:\Users\phillaf\.docker\machine\machines\default
SET DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=default

docker run -it --rm -v /c/Users/phillaf/app:/app -w /app php php %*
```

I can use `php.bat` to run php scripts successfully from the windows command line. In PhpStorm I tried adding `php.bat` as a local PHP interpreter, but it's not recognized as an interpreter.

**2. As a remote interpreter**

I can connect successfully to docker-machine with putty using `docker@192.168.99.100`, password `tcuser`. However PhpStorm seems to be unable to connect with the same infos. I tried setting it up as a remote interpreter.

Under `Settings > Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Interpreters > Remote` I add the SSH info and then click browse. I get the error "failed to send channel request".

Comment: 1) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Docker+Support+in+PhpStorm -- unfortunately it has nothing about PHP Interpreters -- only setting up remote debugging via browser (for which you do not need PHP Interpreter). 2) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-29645 -- actual ticket for implementing "PHP Remote Interpreter with Docker" -- hopefully will be available in 2016.3 version

Comment: 3) I cannot say why `php.bat` does not work .. but most likely because IDE checks it's output and it's either does not return it .. or returns in unexpected format/unexpected channel or whatever. Plus, since files would not be located locally, it would have limited usage cases (you would need to use correct remote paths for files .. right?)